# Antd Range Picker make possible to set start date if it is before already chosen start date

Tags: antd

how can I do functional for antd Range Picker to select date which is before selected start date?
but these dates are disabled by default and I can't undisable them
case for default antd Range Picker
antd version: "4.23.1"

functional I need:

1. select start date
2. make possible to choose dates before chosen start date
3. when choosing dates before **current start date** replace it instead of setting to end date
4. if selected date is after start date, work as default, set to end

[on this step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8x0c.png)

so, here I faced 2 problems: how can I enable dates before selected start date and then how to replace current start date

Comment: Not found in official doc - https://ant.design/components/date-picker#rangepicker